# Заменить одинарные кавычки на двойные, минуя апостроф

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как можно заменить одинарные кавычки на двойные, не трогая апостроф? В теории нужно проверить чтоб одинарная кавычка не стояла между буквами. Но регулярка:

```
/([^а-я]\'[^а-я])/u
```

...не помогает.

Comment: А еще можно `"~\b'\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'~u"`, наверное. Или `"~\B'\b|\b'\B~u"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте просмотры назад/вперёд в комплекте с подмасками:

```
$str = "Д'артаньян и 'три' мушектёра";

$patt = '~(?<!\pL)\'(.+?)\'(?!\pL)~u';
$repl = '"$1"';

echo preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);
```

Результат:

```
Д'артаньян и "три" мушектёра
```